# How to upload different context configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, config

Collegues, i have main class which looks like:

```
public class App {

    static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {



            switch (args[i]) {
                case "OrderUpload":
                    ApplicationContext ctxOrderUpload =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfigBasic.class);
                    OrderUpload OrderUpload = ctxOrderUpload.getBean(OrderUpload.class);
                    OrderUpload.process();
                    break;
                case "TrdUpload":
                    ApplicationContext ctxTrdUpload = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
                    TrdUpload TrdUpload = ctxTrdUpload.getBean(TrdUpload.class);
                    TrdUpload.process();
                    break;
                default:
                    LOG.info("Process is not defined - > " + args[i]);
                    System.exit(0);
            }

        }
 }
```

And i have two config classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan

public class AppConfigBasic {}
```

and Extended config

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan

public class AppConfig extends AppConfigBasic {}
```

Why when execute `java -jar app.jar OrderUpload` Spring loads beans from AppConfig too (not only from AppConfigBasic`)?
How two use different context config files for differen cases in switch?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your `@ComponentScan` in the `AppConfigBasic` - it should be including your `AppConfig` (don't forget `@ComponentScan` is also scanning `@Configuration` beans).

Be more specific in your `@ComponentScan` not to include the package of your `AppConfig` or alternative (and probably preferrably) use the `@ComponentScan` [excludeFilters functionality](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--).